# how to handle big loops in python?

Tags: python

This is more to do with my code as i'm sure i'm doing something wrong

all i'm trying to do is call a main function to repeated itself with a recursive number that at some point i'll reset.

here is my code

```
sys.setrecursionlimit(8000)
didMenuFinish = 0

def mainThread(interval):
    time.sleep(0.2)
    print("interval is: " + str(interval))
    
    if (interval < 1650):
        raceTrack(interval)
    if (interval == 1680):
        resetButtons()
        restartRace()


    if didMenuFinish==0:
        mainThread(interval + 1)
    else:
        didMenuFinish = 0
        mainThread(0)

time.sleep(4)
keyboard.press(Key.enter)
keyboard.release(Key.enter)
mainThread(0)
```

At first the main thread runs fine, but somewhere in the 2500 interval +- it just stops with the error code for stack overflow

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)
```

I am using Windows and pyCharm

do you know how I can handle that ? or am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: I don't see a way that your recursive function ever has a termination condition (i.e. doesn't call itself) therefore eventually you will get a Stack Overflow from endless recursion.

Comment: It runs recursive calls, so there is too many for you workstation

Comment: hi @CoryKramer i actually dont want to it to stop, i want a loop that will just do that thing over and over again always

Comment: @kj-crypto all i want is a loop that will repeate itself always, it's fine with me that it will happen again and again and again always

Comment: Then you should just use a normal loop (like `while`) otherwise using recursion this crash is inevitable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely recursively looping forever. You recursively call `mainThread` in these parts:

```py
def mainThread(interval):
    # ...
    if didMenuFinish == 0:
        mainThread(interval + 1)
    else:
        didMenuFinish = 0
        mainThread(0)
```

But you never `return` to the caller. You need a base case that stops the recursive loop

---

Consider this example of a recursive factorial function:

```py
def fac(x):
    if x <= 1:
        return 1
    return x*fac(x-1)
```

The base case (terminating case) is when `x <= 1`. and this will be reached eventually as `fac(x-1)` implies that `x` is decreasing towards the conditional `x <= 1`. i.e. you need to have some sort of case where recursion is not needed. Your current function is recursively equivalent to:

```
def foo():
    foo()
```

---

Perhaps infinitely looping and locally updating variables will work?

```py
def mainThread(interval):
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.2)
        print(f"interval is: " {interval})
        
        if interval < 1650:
            raceTrack(interval)
        if interval == 1680:
            resetButtons()
            restartRace()


        if didMenuFinish == 0:
            # No need to call the function again. just change the local variable
            interval += 1
        else:
            didMenuFinish = 0
            # Same here
            interval = 0
```

Comment: i understand what you mean but i want a loop that will always happen i dont want that loop to stop, so i understand i'm doing what you setup in the example i just want it as so, that it will alwyas keep repeating itself like endless loop that will go over it again and again

Comment: Would a `While True` loop work?

Comment: I've appended a solution. But it is the same as @fafl's answer. fafl may have your desired solution

Comment: Thanks, Wouldn't this just run once though ?  how can we make this run over and over again ?

Comment: It's in a `while True` loop. It will run until the program breaks

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a stack overflow error because your recursive calls never terminate.

Try using a loop instead:

```
def mainThread(interval):
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.2)
        print("interval is: " + str(interval))
        
        if (interval < 1650):
            raceTrack(interval)
        if (interval == 1680):
            resetButtons()
            restartRace()

        if didMenuFinish==0:
            interval += 1
        else:
            didMenuFinish = 0
            interval = 0
```